# slack bot RTM API monitor the channel's activity

Tags: events, bots, slack-api, slack, rtm

I am using simple template of slack bot RTM API, that is given at https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk

I want to monitor the channel's activity, for example, is channel is salient (no messages) for few minutes, I want to send some message.

How to do so? If it's possible to intervene into the ping/pong event?

Comment: When certain submission was posted to a slack channel, if you want to response for the submission using script, you can use "Outgoing Webhooks". The detail information is here. https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks This can do POST from slack to your server when certain submission was posted. So if you use it, a server for receiving the post from slack is required. If you have no server, don't worry, you can use Google Apps Script as a server. I think that by using this, you can monitor frequency of post messages.

Comment: what you've described it's the same event-based communication, the question is how to send the message when the channel is silent.

Comment: Frequency of post messages shows the condition of the channel. I thought that when the frequency of post messages is low, the channel means silent. I think that the condition can be retrieved by differentiating the frequency by time, when creates a sample script. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.